# Using url parameters in golang template code

Tags: go

I'm new to Go and trying to modify some code written by someone else. Right now he tests the stored value of a given day to determine if someone took lunch that day or not.

What I want to do is see if there's a stored value and if there isn't, use the default value which is passed via URL parameter. The code looks like this:

```
<input id="lunch{{.place}}" type="checkbox" {{if index .week.NoMeals .place}} checked {{end}}>
```

I have a URL variable set like so:

```
sitename?nolunch=1
```

So the logic I want is that if the stored data for that day is set, the checkbox will reflect the stored value. If it hasn't been set, the box should be checked if the nolunch URL parameter is set and not checked if it's not.

How do I test for url parameters in Go template code?

Comment: Go templates don't know anything about the URL or any other part of the request / response. They only have whatever data you pass in to them. Look to where you're executing the template and see if you can give it something useful

Comment: Is it possible to create variables based on values in the URL or in JS?

Comment: Yeah, check out the URL field of https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request as well as https://golang.org/pkg/net/url/#URL.Query

Comment: @not_a_generic_user, you can use JS of course, but you can also create a "renderTemplate" function and pass a map with URL params in the context.

Comment: What would a line of code that brings a url variable (or JS variable since I can get URL variables with JS) into go so I can test the logic look like?